# How do i set authorized access to action methods based on DB tables?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i have a `mst_roles` table in db with followingstructure

```
id  RoleName
1    Admin
2    Manager
3    Operator
```

the `mst_users` table is like this

```
id   username password RoleId
1     bob      123      2
2     rick     777      3
```

in my MVC i have a controller `Orders` with two action methods

```
public ActionResult TakeOrder()
{

}

public ActionResult StopAllTransactions()
{

}
```

How do i let only the Role **Manager** access the `StopAllTransaction()` and **Operator** has the access to `TakeOrder()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action Method :

```
[AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute(Roles = "Role1,Role2")]
public ActionResult Welcome()
{
  return View();
}
```

Custom Class :

```
public class AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Roles { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
        {
            //Bind User Roles from Database here
            string userRoles = "Role1,Role2,Role3";

            if (userRoles.IndexOf(Roles) > -1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
}
```

Comment: but how i'm going to map that Roles="admin" to DB table's record id=1, RoleName="Admin" how does MVC know the Roles="admin" refers to the one in the DB table?

Comment: You need to override the method 'AuthorizeCore' of class 'AuthorizeAttribute' in your custom class. I will update my code in the previous example.

Comment: im new to this topic so i have to ask this question, if you bind usersRoles like AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute(Roles = "Role1,Role2") it not going to access a database table instead a harcodes string property string userRoles = "Role1,Role2,Role3";
 in the AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute class right... so DB roles tables is in away useless because even i add new roles to table i still have to update the hard coded string userRoles = "Role1,Role2,Role3";
property becuase the authorization happens through this string. Also i suppose i have to follow the same technique for auhorize by Users?

Comment: You need to bind the comma separated roles for the logged-in user in "userRoles" variable from the database.  You need to query the database to get all the roles for the logged-in user.

Comment: Assume i have logged in as Manager Role, but How does the the authorization attribute knows i'm the manager role? In the forms athentication in the authentication cookie i only store my use name so how does it know that user name belongs to a manager?