# When i use role based authorization how does it knows currenly logged in users Role?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Assume i have the following Role based authorization for an action

```
[AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute(Roles = "Manager")]
public ActionResult Welcome()
{
  return View();
}
```

here is the AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute class

```
public class AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public string Roles { get; set; }

        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContextBase)
        {
            //Bind User Roles from Database here
            string userRoles = "Manager,Supervisor,Inspector";

            if (userRoles.IndexOf(Roles) > -1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
}
```

I have separate DB tables `Roles` and `Users`

Assume the current user logged in is of `Role` **Manager**. How does this `"AuthorizeDBRoleAttribute"` attribute knows the current user's `role` so it can let access to the Action method

How to setup Role based authorization was discussed in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866761/how-do-i-set-authorized-access-to-action-methods-based-on-db-tables). I want to drag it a bit further in to the next step on how MVC figure out the current user's role etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start with current `IPrincipal`, taken from the http context and set there by the authentication module.

Then, depending on your current approach (which we obviously don't know) you either have roles already stored in the principal object or you have only the user name and you retrieve roles from the database for the current user name.

The author of the code you cite even put a comment there - retrieve user roles for the current user name, more or less something like:

```
 string username = httpContextBase.User.Identity.Name;

 var roles = whereeverYourRolesAreStored.RolesForUser( username );
```

Comment: my roles are fetched from DB's 'mst_Roles' table

Comment: Is it a standard to retrieve all roles names from db to server when the application starts for the first time or this is done on user login based, on each login re-fetch all users

Comment: @PhillGreggan: I guess you really don't gain much by caching role names. How would you use the cache then? Upon logging of each user you still have to query the db for his/her roles.

Comment: so which method is the best approach

Comment: @PhillGreggan: who is Stephen Muecke and how is he related to my answer here? As for the question of the best approach - such questions are not quite welcome here on SO as purely opinion based.

Comment: OK but i can ask for suggestion or a recommended approach ?

Comment: @PhillGreggan: sure, my opinion is that if your `IPrincipal` is the `ClaimsPrincipal`, you could cache roles in `Role` claims. If not (for example you use good old Forms authentication, you could safely have an extra query in the authorize attribute. Yet, I still wonder why would you create a custom attribute, considering the built-in `Authorize` already supports roles. The only reason I can think of is you **don't want** to have roles cached anywhere, you want them read from the DB upon each request.

Comment: thanks for the explanation there, i use forms authentication : )